# kate search/replace with special characters?

Tags: kate

Is there any way I can replace something with special character like \n, \t at so on?
I can search with regex, and I can even use something like \1 to refer to the group. But I am surprised the \n,\t will be treated literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Mode` drop down list in `Find/Replace` panel. Just select the `Escape sequences` option there and you'll be able to replace something with special characters.